# Count records with missing keys using jq

Tags: json, bash, count, jq, missing-data

Below is a sample output that is returned when calling an API:

```
curl "https://mywebsite.com/api/cars.json&page=1" |  jq '.'
```

Using `jq`, how would one count the number or records where the `charge` key is missing?  I understand that the first bit of code would include `jq '. | length'` but how would one filter out objects that contain or don't contain a certain key value ?

If applied to the sample below, the output would be `1`

```
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "vehicleA",
      "state": "available",
      "charge": 100
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "vehicleB",
      "state": "available",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "vehicleB",
      "state": "available",
      "charge": 50
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`map`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) and [`length`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#length):

```
.items | map(select(.charge == null)) | length
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/1KIqTcoRWt)

Here is a more efficient solution using [`reduce`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce):

```
reduce (.items[] | select(.charge == null)) as $i (0;.+=1)
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/5Uc6-Lkxpv)

Sample Run (assuming corrected JSON data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -M 'reduce (.items[] | select(.charge == null)) as $i (0;.+=1)' data.json
1
```

Note that each of the above takes a minor shortcut assuming that the items won't have a `"charge":null` member.  If some items could have a `null` charge then the test for `== null` won't distinguish between those items and items without the `charge` key.  If this is a concern the following forms of the above filters which use [`has`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#has(key)) are better:

```
.items | map(select(has("charge")|not)) | length

reduce (.items[] | select(has("charge")|not)) as $i (0;.+=1)
```

Comment: when I try this: `curl "https://mywebsite.com/api/cars.json&page=1" |  .items | map(select(.charge == null)) | length`  I get the following error: 
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `select'

Comment: I was only showing the filter.  The complete jq command would be `curl ... | jq -M '.items | map(select(.charge == null)) | length'`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that uses a simple but powerful utility function worthy perhaps of your standard library:

```
def sigma(stream): reduce stream as $s (null; . + $s);
```

The filter you'd use with this would be:

```
sigma(.items[] | select(has("charge") == false) | 1)
```

This is very efficient as no intermediate array is required, and no useless additions of 0 are involved. Also, as mentioned elsewhere, using `has` is more robust than making assumptions about the value of `.charge`.

#### Startup file

If you have no plans to use jq's module system, you can simply add the above definition of `sigma` to the file ~/.jq and invoke jq like so:

```
jq 'sigma(.items[] | select(has("charge") == false) | 1)'
```

Better yet, if you also add `def count(s): sigma(s|1);` to the file, the invocation would simply be:

```
jq 'count(.items[] | select(has("charge") | not))'
```

#### Standard Library

If for example ~/.jq/jq/jq.jq is your standard library, then assuming `count/1` is included in this file, you could invoke jq like so:

```
jq 'include "jq"; count(.items[] | select(has("charge") == false))'
```

Comment: I think **add** could be defined using **sigma** ( e.g. `def add: sigma(.[]);` )

Comment: Yes, because both start with `null`, as they should (in jq) because `+` is polymorphic.

Comment: @jq170727 - Speaking of streams, I'd appreciate any comments/suggestions/corrections you may have regarding https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq

Comment: I will need more time but here are some thoughts after a very quick read. • I think the idea of focusing on the stream/sequence nature of jq is a good one but may be confusing without some kind of short discussion or example early on of what the "current value" is/means from a streaming perspective.  • A few graphic diagrams breaking down the early examples would help (although choosing good ones may not be easy). • The overall ratio of new-concepts to text in each section might be a little high.  A more general audience might benefit from more repetition of concepts from section to section.

Comment: What do you think about showing successive values in separate vertical "swimlanes" with the current value of different parts of the filter shown horizontally?  e.g. [example.png](https://gist.github.com/jq170727/6e31e97d9b1e5eb20c1f4536519a5b4d)

Comment: As a matter of fact, after reading your previous comment, I added a `jq '1,2'` transcript (see "as illustrated by this three-line transcript").  Could I use your .png ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159557/discussion-between-peak-and-jq170727).